# Timers and push button interface stm32

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery

How to develop a program so that when we press the push button a timer should start, and if the push button is pressed for more than 5 seconds message should get transmitted via UART and if the timer is below 5 seconds an error message should come up.

I need help with how to interface push button and timer in stm.

Comment: no i need help with how to interface push button and timer in stm

Comment: What framework (STM HAL, Arduino etc.) are you using?

Comment: STM HAL  is the framework

Comment: What you have done so far? Show us :)

Comment: You should probably start with a tutorial about GPIO programming with HAL (for the button). Once that works you can move on to similar tutorials about timers and UART. https://simonmartin.ch/resources/stm32/dl/STM32%20Tutorial%2001%20-%20GPIO%20Operations%20using%20HAL%20(and%20FreeRTOS).pdf https://medium.com/vicara-hardware-university/stm32-guide-gpio-and-buttons-8303e6c8cb44 https://letanphuc.net/2015/02/stm32f0-tutorial-gpio-blinking-led-cubemx-keil-source-insight/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Regardless of your framework you can implement this algorithm which detects button press and release.
To do so, you need to enable the EXTI on both rising and falling edges.
The EXTI handler would look like:

```
  EXTI_Handler ()
  {
    /* resolve button status according GPIO value transition */
    if (button_pushed)
      {
        start_timer ().
      }
    else if (button_released)
      {
        local_seconds_count = get_timer_count_in_seconds ();
        if (local_seconds_count > 5)
          {
            /* 5s have elapsed */
            send_uart (OK_MSG);
          } 
        else
          {
            send_uart (ERR_MSG);
          }
        /* stop timer */
        stop_timer ();
      }
  }
```

Other ideas may be basing on SysTick timer and HAL_GetTicks: just use one global variable to store button press instant and compare+clear it on release.

You can find a great tutorial on STM32 timer in [visualgdb site](https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/arm/stm32/timers/).
For EXTI refer to [this page](https://deepbluembedded.com/stm32-external-interrupt-example-lab/).